# SourceTree stopped showing changes in XAML files

Tags: xaml, atlassian-sourcetree

Under `SourceTree`, when you click a file on the list, it nicely shows the changes made to it.

Suddendly, my `SourceTree` stopped showing edits made into a `XAML` file. The window showing the edits is completely blank even if there are edits made to the XAML file. 
Previously the edits were showing correctly but suddendly they stopped to be shown.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Is there a way to fix this somehow?

Comment: Is this only the one file or all XAML files?

Comment: The problem is only with this one XAML file. Edits in other XAML files are shown correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this.

The `XAML` file was very big with lot of changes and `SourceTree` was configured to view differences only up to a certain magnitude.

Under `SourcTree`, you can go Tools->Options and specify Size Limit (Text) and Size Limit (Binary) values. By increasing these values the differences in `XAML` are again showing.

[image]